# Using RabbitMQ with Plone - Celery or not?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, plone, celery

I hope I am posting this in the right place.

I am researching RabbitMQ for potential use in our Plone sites. We currently us Async on a dedicated worker client in the Plone server, but we are thinking about building a dedicated RabbitMQ server that will handle all Plone messaging and other activity.

My specific question is, what are the advantages of using Celery to work with RabbitMQ in Plone versus just using RabbitMQ? I found [this plone add-on](https://github.com/mjpieters/plone.app.celery) for Celery integration, but not sure if that is best route to go. I noticed Celery has the Flower tool for monitoring the queues, which would be a huge plus.

As a side question, if you feel so inclined, does anyone have any tips or references for integration RabbitMQ with Plone to handle all of these requests? I have been doing research, and get the general gist of RabbitMQ, but I can't seem to make the connection with Plone activities, such as Content Rules and PloneFormGen submissions for example. So far I see [this add-on](https://github.com/datakurre/collective.zamqp) that I am going to install and see if I can figure out, but I am just trying to get a little guidance if I can.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, ask yourself, if you need the features of RabbitMQ or just want to do some asynchronous tasks in Python with Plone.

If you don't really need RabbitMQ, you could look into David Glick's gists for how to integrate Celery with Plone (and still use RabbitMQ with Celery):

- https://gist.github.com/davisagli/5824662
- https://gist.github.com/davisagli/5824709

You could also look into [collective.taskqueue](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.taskqueue) (simple queues without Celery nor RabbitMQ), but it does not provide any monitoring solution yet.

If you really need RabbitMQ, skip Celery, and try out [collective.zamqp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.zamqp). Celery tries to be broker by itself and would prevent you from using most of AMQP's and RabbitMQ's built-in features.

RabbitMQ ships with great web admin plugin for monitoring and there are also plugins for 3rd party monitoring systems (like Zenoss).

I'm sorry that [collective.zamqp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.zamqp) is still missing narrative documentation, but you can look into [collective.zamqpdemo](https://github.com/datakurre/collective.zamqpdemo) for various examples of its configuration and usage.

In short, c.zamqp allows you to define configure broker usage in terms of producers and consumers:

```py
from five import grok
from zope.interface import Interface
from collective.zamqp.producer import Producer
from collective.zamqp.consumer import Consumer


class CreateItemProducer(Producer):
    """Produces item creation requests"""
    grok.name("amqpdemo.create")  # is also used as default routing key

    connection_id = "superuser"
    serializer = "msgpack"
    queue = "amqpdemo.create"

    durable = False


class ICreateItemMessage(Interface):
    """Marker interface for item creation message"""


class CreateItemConsumer(Consumer):
    """Consumes item creation messages"""
    grok.name("amqpdemo.create")  # is also used as the queue name

    connection_id = "superuser"
    marker = ICreateItemMessage

    durable = False
```

Publish messages through transaction bound producer (to publish messages only after a successful transaction):

```py
    import uuid

    from zope.component import getUtility
    from collective.zamqp.interfaces import IProducer

    producer = getUtility(IProducer, name="amqpdemo.create")
    producer._register()  # register to bound to successful transaction

    message = {"title": u"My title"}

    producer.publish(message)
```

And consume the messages in a familiar content event handler environment:

```py
from zope.component.hooks import getSite
from collective.zamqp.interfaces import IMessageArrivedEvent
from plone.dexterity.utils import createContentInContainer

@grok.subscribe(ICreateItemMessage, IMessageArrivedEvent)
def createItem(message, event):
    """Consume item creation message"""

    portal = getSite()
    obj = createContentInContainer(
        portal, "Document", checkConstraints=True, **message.body)

    message.ack()
```

Finally, it decouples broker connection configuration from code and the actual connection parameters can be defined in buildout.cfg (allowing required amount of consuming instances):

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
...
zope-conf-additional =
    %import collective.zamqp
    <amqp-broker-connection>
         connection_id superuser
         heartbeat 120
# These are defaults, but can be defined when required:     
#        hostname localhost
#        virtual_host /
#        username guest
#        password guest
    </amqp-broker-connection>
    <amqp-consuming-server>
        connection_id superuser
        site_id Plone
        user_id admin
        vhm_method_prefix /VirtualHostBase/https/example.com:443/Plone/VirtualHostRoot
    </amqp-consuming-server>
```

c.zamqp cannot be directly called from RestrictedPython, so integrating it to PloneFormGen would need either a custom action adapter or a custom External method to be called from PFG's Python script adapter.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide such a detailed explanation! I think I get most of what you are saying here... so what about content rules? If I want to route all content rule emails that are triggered through RabbitMQ, do I need to create a custom CR action, or is there another way to connect? I think I'm just not getting how to get Plone activity to actually use Rabbit. I went with c.zamqp for my first effort btw.

Comment: I don't have a sure solution for queuing email sends. You could create a custom CR action for sure, but there's already support for queueing email sending in Products.MailHost and zope.sendmail. So, at least in theory, you could create your own email queue, which would deliver emails into RabbitMQ (either using c.zamqp or just bare rabbitpy-library commands, because MailHost already has transaction manager for emails). Yet, for this you should really read through Products.MailHost and zope.sendmail and look into MailHost tool in Plone root.